transforming a plane using rotation and translation
I am trying to generate oblique slices through a 3D volume and for this I need to rotate the cutting plane.
So, initially I describe the plane as containing the point (0, 0, 0) and basically the normal being (0, 1, 0), so the cutting plane is XZ.
Now, suppose I have a 4x4 transformation matrix, encapsulating rotation and translation. If I want to get this cutting plane, is it enough to transform the point and the normal vector and we have all the parameters of the cutting plane?

I want to slice the 3D volume. Sorry if that was not clear from the question. Like I said, I want to cut a slice out of the 3D volume.
